# Script to combine multiple scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

The script below does not work as expected. Can anybody help me to check if I missed anything? Gives me error **TypeError: Cannot call method "getValue" of null**. I run the script again and it goes through but doesn't change anything on the file.

Below are the parts of the script and how they should work:

**First** part is to automatically get data from the CSV Reports in Keyword Inspector. I have this "Settings" sheet where it has the password, email, and URL Links to the reports. > first part works fine.

**Second** part is to paste data in the "GetCSV" sheet. But first we must check if we have data in the first three columns, if there is any existing data we must move all data to the right. We paste what we get from the .csv file in "GetCSV" sheet, in Column 2, Row 2. In Column 1, row 2 we paste date and time format starting from A2 down to the last row with data:

```js
    setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM-dd HH:mm AM/PM"));
```

**Third** part, we copy the same data we updated to its final destination "Data" sheet, starting from the first empty row.

I am not very savvy with the Java script and I already have this script in place, I just need to modify it a bit based on my needs.

```js
    function getCsv(){

  //populateSheetWithCSV("http://simple.keywordinspector.com/simple/download.php?id=12612", "###.#####@gmail.com", "Abc12345")
  //;
  //var settingsSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("settings");


  var passCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("password");
  //getRange("B3");
  var emailCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("email");
  Logger.log(emailCell)

  var cp = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_512, passCell.getValue());
  var sp = '';
    for (i = 0; i < cp.length; i++) {
      var byte = cp[i];
      if (byte < 0)
        byte += 256;
      var byteStr = byte.toString(16);
      // Ensure we have 2 chars in our byte, pad with 0
      if (byteStr.length == 1) byteStr = '0'+byteStr;
      sp += byteStr;
    }   
  var payload =
   {
     "email" : emailCell.getValue(),
     "password" : "",
     "p" : sp
   }
  Logger.log(cp);
  //return; 
  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : false
   };
  var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://simple.keywordinspector.com/simple/process_login.php" ,     options);
  login.getContentText()
  var sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];

  Logger.log(sessionDetails)

  var csvUrlId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("URL_Id").getValue(); 
  var csvUrls  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("URLS").getValues(); 

  Logger.log(csvUrls[csvUrlId-1]);

  var downloadCsv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrls[csvUrlId-1]     ,//"http://simple.keywordinspector.com/simple/download.php?id=12612", 
                              {"headers" : {"Cookie" : sessionDetails},
                               "method" : "post",
                               "payload" : payload
                              });
  //Logger.log(downloadCsv.getContentText())

  var csvContent = Utilities.parseCsv(downloadCsv.getContentText());

  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GetCSV");
  var fisrtEmptyColumn 
  for (i=1 ; i<1024 ; (i=i+2))  {
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,i,1,1);
    if (range.isBlank()) {
      firstEmptyColumn = i
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(firstEmptyColumn);

  for (i = firstEmptyColumn ; i>3 ; i=i-3){
    Logger.log(i)
    var rangeToCopy =sheet.getRange(1, i-3 ,sheet.getMaxRows(),3);
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, i));
  }

  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,2) 
  var A1not = sheet.getRange(3, 2, sheet.getMaxRows()-2, 1).getA1Notation();
  cell.setFormula("=COUNTA("+A1not+")");

  //
  for (i = firstEmptyColumn ; i>4 ; i=i-2){
    for (j = 3; j < sheet.getMaxRows()-2 ; j++){

  var cell = sheet.getRange(j,1);

  cell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM-dd HH:mm AM/PM"));

  sheet.getRange(2, 2, csvContent.length   /* rows */, csvContent[0].length /* columns */).setValues(csvContent);


  firstEmptyColumn = firstEmptyColumn +2 ;
  if (firstEmptyColumn>21) {
    firstEmptyColumn = 21
      }

  Logger.log(firstEmptyColumn);

  var sourcesheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GetCSV");
  var SourceRange = sourcesheet.getRange(3, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());

  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");;
  var targetRange = target.getRange(target.getLastRow() + 1, 2);

  SourceRange.copyTo(targetRange)
 }

 var cell = sourcesheet.getRange("A1")

    for (j = target.getlastrow() +1; j < sheet.getMaxRows()-2 ; j++){

      var targetRange2 = target.getRange(j,1);

      cell.copyto(targetRange2)
    }


  }
  }
```

Comment: initial error would say TypeError: Cannot call method "getValue" of null. Then when I run the script again, it would say "finish" but it doesn't do anything. No changes to the file whatsoever.

Comment: 1. you are missing the most important tag for google apps script (which ive added) 2. suspicious to have so many upvotes. 3. look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting so you can debug this. also review javascript syntax for many missing semicolons at the end of each line

Comment: It's important to understand the error message.  In object oriented programing (OOP) the named code that runs is called a "Method".  A "Method" is (For all practical purposes) exactly the same as a function, it just has a different name because it's inside of an object.  When you see the error `TypeError: Cannot call method "getValue" of null`.  You might spend lots of time trying to figure out what is wrong with the `getValue()` method, when there is nothing wrong with it.  `getValue()` has a dot in front of it, and the name of something before that.  `getValue()` works on the `Range`.

Comment: And the **Range** is null.  The error message doesn't give you the name of the range.  But what you need to be looking for, is a problem with the *range*.  The value type of the range is *Null*.  Your range isn't getting set properly.  That's why the error msg states **TypeError:**.  Every value has a type.  The value type could be a number, or text or date, or undefined, or null, etc.  A method can't run on an object that has a value type of null.  That's how to understand the error.  If you don't understand the error, you don't know where to look.